# === operator and Eclipse IDE

Tags: node.js, eclipse

So I have just starting out with node.js and has got some sample apps up and running from an SDK that I am playing around with.

I'm using Eclipse with AWS IoT Device SDK

I'm now looking at another part of the SDK and the code fails in my IDE

```
The code is if (clientTokenUpdate === null)
           {
              console.log('update shadow failed, operation still in progress');
           }
           }, 5000 );
```

Its complaining about the === with an error

***Unexpected token 
 ===***

Anyone got any ideas on this and where I should start looking? I very new to both node and eclipse and developing in general.

Any help is greatly appreciated
Tks

Comment: Whats the full error?  Are you sure the IDE doesn't think you are editing a Java file rather than a JavaScript file?

Comment: Hi Bob

That is the full error in the Problems section of the Eclipse IDE. The type of the error is listed as Javascript Problem and the little icon next to the filename is a white rectangle with JS on it so I'm pretty confident that its a Javascript project

Comment: Hi Bob

I found that the IDE was complaining on that line due to an error just a bit further up in the code due to a missing }

Compiles fine now.

Appreciate you taking the time to respond